# Comments pane for current buffer that you can jump to such as TODO:, WARN:, and NOTE:?

Tags: comments

A while ago I used to use eclipse as my IDE, and I remember you could add `TODO: some task`, `NOTE: some comment`, `WARN: some warning` to your code, and it would appear in a particular pane for the current buffer, so you could click and jump to that section of the code.

I'm aware of marks, and of the ability to search for such things in vim, but is there a way to open a similar pane to see an overview lines with this text in vim so that you can "jump to them"?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are after but perhaps `:vimgrep TODO: % | cl`

Comment: @grochmal That actually does kinda work.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, guys! I had a lot fun writing https://github.com/lsrdg/beback.vim (: